# RabbitMQ queues pile up with messages over a period of time even though there are listeners associated with those queues

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have a situation in my rabbitmq setup. My scenario is as below,

**Setup:**

1. There are 2 Virtual machines involved.
2. Both the VMs are sending 25mb size messages every  7 seconds in loop.
3. There are shovels setup for transmitting the messages between the machines.
4. Both the machines have listeners to consume the messages sent by the other machine.
5. Listeners just consume the messages and comes out. There is no processing involved at the listener side.
6. There rabbitmQ broker is **SSL enabled**.
7. I am using **Spring RabbitMq**.
8. I am using **SimpleMessageListenerContainer** for listening.

**My Issues:**

1. Over a period of time, say after 1.5 days of continuous message exchange, 
   there is accumulation of messages in the queues.
2. The listeners are up but the consumption rate diminishes over a period of time 
   and the messages pile up in the queue.
3. Some of the messages accumulated in the queue are in unacked state.

**Things i want to try:**

1. Increase the no. of listeners for the queue.
2. Increase the prefetch count for the listener.

**My Question**

1. Why the messages got accumulated over the period of time.
2. was there any network disturbance in between. Do i need to add extra parameters for listeners to tackle network disturbances.

Please guide me here. I need help in fine tuning my setup to make it more robust.

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for your inputs.. I am using rabbitmq 3.6.10 version only.   Some more inputs about my setup :  1. Its a java process running at both the vms. 2. There are 25 queues at both the machines. 3. The sender process spawns 25 threads and sends 25mb of data every 7 seconds. The gap between each thread is 7 seconds. 4. There are 25 shovels created to pump messages from sender to reciever machine. 5. At the reciever side, there is only **one listener for all the 25 queues**.  Please tell me what extra info u need.

Answer (score 0):

It would be very difficult for someone here to debug your application.

> consumption rate diminishes over a period of time

That is most like a symptom of your application rather that the messaging system or framework. I would start there.

> was there any network disturbance in between.

With recent versions of RabbitMQ, heartbeats are enabled by default so any such "disturbances" should be detected ok.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your inputs.. I am using rabbitmq 3.6.10 version only. Some more inputs about my setup : 1. Its a java process running at both the vms. 2. There are 25 queues at both the machines. 3. The sender process spawns 25 threads and sends 25mb of data every 7 seconds. The gap between each thread is 7 seconds. 4. There are 25 shovels created to pump messages from sender to reciever machine. 5. At the reciever side, there is only one listener for all the 25 queues. Please tell me what extra info u need.

Comment: @vinodhy What was the root cause?